# I need a formula that flags after 45 days

Tags: excel, excel-formula, flags

I need a formula that will generate a flag.  Basically Column A would have a specific date.  I need the next column to generate a flag if the current date is 45 days after the original (A).

I'm not sure how to type in the formula.

Comment: What are you talking about? you need to post a language and give a better context, to what your doing

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, start with [How to ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @johnny5, she tagged Excel. She's asking how to type the formula to achieve her desired output.

Comment: @rwking johnny5 commented before I edited the tags.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to utilize is an `if` statement with the `TODAY()` function.

Here's an example of how to accomplish what you're looking for. I added some conditional formatting to help color code the result.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use conditional formatting to get this result.

Highlight the cell (or range of cells) that you want to be flagged if the trigger point is hit and click "Conditional formatting" -> "New Rule".

From the new window that opened, select the bottom option that should be "Use a formula to determine which cells to format".

In the box in the bottom half of the "New Formatting Rule" window, type the following:

```
=(Today()-A1)>45
```

Note: A1 should be the first cell in the range you selected to check (the dates) and 45 is the number of days from today you want to be the flag.

Then click the "Format" button to apply what ever kind of flag you want.

[image]

In the above example, the cell will be filled red and text will be set to white. This would be a good conditional formatting rule to apply to the actual date range so that the date itself is flagged.